# Will A EVGA 500W Power Supply Power a GTX 960?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power

I am thinking of getting this graphics card for my PC:
[http://www.amazon.com/EVGA-GeForce-Whisper-Graphics-02G-P4-2966-KR/dp/B00SC6HAS4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SC6HAS4)

I am not sure if my 500W power supply can handle this card:
http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=100-W1-0500-KR

The graphics card has a recommended PSU of anything above 400W, but will my card have the proper connectors to actually connect to the card, and will this power supply be able to handle running this card?

I am sure this isn't the best power supply for the GTX 960, but I would like to be able to keep my current power supply if I get this card. (GPUs already cost enough by themselves.)

Comment: It says the recommended is 400W or more so yes it would be enough, and yes you'll have the proper connectors (they come with the PSU).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am sure this isn't the best power supply for the GTX 960

No, it isn't. But it's still enough.

Using the [eXtreme Power Supply Calculator](http://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator) with the following settings:

- Motherboard: Desktop
- CPU: Intel - LGA 2011-3 - Core i7-5960X
- CPU Utilization: 100% TDP
- Memory: 4x 8GB DDR3 Module
- Video Card - Set 1: NVIDIA - GeForce GTX 960
- Storage: 4 x SATA 7200 RPM HDD's
- Other Devices: 2 x USB 2.0 Devices & 2 x USB 3.0 Devices
- 1 x Standard Keyboard, 1 x Standard Mouse
- Fans: 2 x 80mm, 2x 120mm
- Computer Utilization: Always On (24/7)

I got the following result:

[image]

I used these settings to get a result that's probably higher than you would need.
However it's important to remember that a calculator like this isn't 100% accurate (which is partly why I went "overboard"). If the recommended PSU wattage on your GTX 960 is 400W, then there should be no problem in using a 500W PSU, assuming there aren't any other components that require a higher wattage PSU.

Comment: Do you know what power connectors the GTX 960 uses, and does my power supply have the proper connectors?

Comment: https://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=02G-P4-2966-KR

Check there under "Power type" to see what pins it uses. It's either 6 pin or 8 pin, depending on the specific model.

Comment: The GPU is 8 pin, and the power supply comes with 8 pin connectors that are made of 6 and 2 pin connectors, so I guess that it should work. Thank you, I never needed a GPU that needs extra power from the PSU before, so I wanted to make sure the card would work.